# Generate a random 2x100 matrix

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

I want to generate 1000 points with random positiv coordinates. Then I want to display them as a single 2x1000 matrix.

I generated my points with:

```
counter = 0;
for counter=0:1000
    xPos=randi([0, 100000]);
    yPos=randi([0, 100000]);
end
```

How do I get this into a 2 x 1000 matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
xy = randi(100000, 2, 1000);
```

See the [Matlab `randi` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) for details.

Comment: You're welcome. FYI, you should generally avoid explicit loops in Matlab if you can express what you want to do any other way (e.g. matrix/vector operations or function calls). Loops in Matlab are notoriously slow.

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need is:

```
matrix = randi(100000, [2, 1000]);
```